# Adding duplicate elements by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-events

I am new in Javascript.I need to add duplicate same elements when I click on add more button to add the whole body elements dynamically.Here are the image of my code

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxugM.jpg)

How to do that ? I need your suggestion.Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/clone

Comment: use clone method of jQuery

Comment: @RRR Nijar needs to do it with javascript

Comment: @GauravAggarwal please don't remove tags that are relevant to the question. The OP has tagged jquery therefore you would image they would accept a jQuery solution.

Comment: Yeah but he want to do it javascript only so question should not be tagged as jquery

Comment: That's not your decision to make

Comment: I have not made the decision its mention in question

Comment: @GauravAggarwal manytime ppl tend to address jQuery as javascript unless they mention explicitly "Native/Vanila JS" its natural to think he accepts jQuery as he had tagged jQuery

Comment: JQUERY is a library function of Javascript.So when a beginner found any problem regarding this javascript he should tag javascript and jquery both .. that's why he may get help... @RoryMcCrossan thanks mate i can do it but the another problem is that i cannot binding the events how to do that

Comment: You need to use a delegated event handler, `$parentElement.on('event', 'element selector', func);`. See http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with native javascript

```
element2 = element1.cloneNode(bool)
```

Here boolean indicates whether to clone child nodes or not

Comment: clone() works well,but how to binding the events of javascript?? thanks by the way...

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily in js easily via cloneNode

```js
function cloneFunction() {
    var para = document.getElementById("para-1");
    var cln = para.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(cln);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<p id="para-1">Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>

<button onclick="cloneFunction()">clone it</button>
```